# Comparing the area of similar triangles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

I have the triangle shown below. I have shown that the area of the large triangle is $A_{ABC} = \frac12\cdot12\cdot9 = 54$.

Now, I want to calculate the area of the smaller triangle, and I'm wondering if I have this right.

We see that the hypotenuse of the large triangle is $15$ and the hypotenuse of the small one is $5$. That gives them a length-ratio of $15 / 5 = 3$.

Does that mean that the ratio of the areas is $3^2 = 9$? I.e., can I conclude that the area of the small triangle is $A_{ADE} = 54/3^2 = 6$?

[image]

Comment: Yes $ $ you can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, but make sure that you've proven them to be similar! In your picture, that is obvious, but it may not be in other configurations.

In general, scaling a "shape" by $x$ scales the areas by $x^2$, the volumes by $x^3$, etc.

Comment: Good point! Yes, I preceded this by proving them similar by comparing their angles. Since E=B and they share A, I concluded that C=D, and since they have the same angles, they must be similar.

Comment: Completely correct. Seems like you'll be fine!

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct, they way I proved it is rather simple.
Firstly, if both triangles are similar, then all of the sides are proportional. So If I divide the lengths of the larger triangle over the smaller triangle then

```
                                15/3=9/x=12/y
```

Where x and y are the legs of the smaller triangle.
So if I set 15/3=9/x and I solve for x then I will see that x=3. Therefore, the first leg of the smaller triangle is 3.

Also, 15/3=12/y If I solve for y I will see that y=4. Using this information I can substitute these values into the formula that yields the are of a triangle

```
                               A=(1/2)xy

                              1/2(4)(3)=6
```

and discover that the area of the smaller triangle is, in fact, 6.

Comment: Please use MathJaX formatting, as is standard on this forum.